# Number of maximal cliques in graphs without common neighbourhoods

Tags: graphs

Let's consider a graph $G(n)$ of $n$ vertices such as no two vertices in $G$ have the same exact neighbors (different open neighbourhoods to be more specific; I wonder if this kind of graphs have already a name). Which is the maximum number of maximal cliques of such graphs? Is that amount polynomically bounded?

**Additional related question:** which extra conditions must such graphs have to be planar? This is in fact a related question because planar graph does indeed have a polynomically bounded amount of maximal cliques.

Comment: Doesn't an $n$-clique satisfy your condition?

Comment: @Ariel But it would have the maximum number of maximal cliquies: one

Comment: @Ariel the utility graph doesn't satify my condition and it's a 1-clique if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Any connected graph can be converted to your graph by adding a pendant vertex on each vertex of the graph. And the number of vertices only increases twice. Therefore, you can reduce your problem to a general connected graph.

Comment: Let $M$ be the Moon–Moser graph $K_{3,3,\cdots,3}$ with $3k$ vertices $v_{i,j}$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $j=1,2,\cdots,k$. Let $G$ be $M$ with additional vertices $u_1, u_2$ and additional edges $\{v_{1,j}, u_1\}$ and  $\{v_{2,j}, u_2\}$ for all $j$. Check that all neighbourhoods are different. For $k\ge2$, the number of maximum cliques is $3^k = 3^{\frac{n-2}3}=\omega((\sqrt{n}!)^c)$ for any constant $c$, where $\sqrt{n}!$ is Yuval's answer.

Comment: @JohnL. I guess $n$ is the number of vertices of $G$ and you are substracting $u_1$ and $u_2$ right? and what mathematical identity have you used to get the last formula?

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the number of vertices of $G$. I should have written "For $k\ge3$" instead of "For $k\ge2$". Note that $$\frac{\log((\sqrt{n}!)^c)}{\log(3^{k})} \lt\frac{\log\left(\left(\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt n}\right)^c\right)}{\log(3^{\frac{n-2}3})} =\frac{c\sqrt n \log \sqrt n}{\frac{n-2}3\log 3}=\frac{\frac{c\sqrt n}2 \log n}{\frac{n-2}3\log 3}\sim\frac{\frac{c\sqrt n}2 \log n}{\frac{n}3\log 3}= \frac{3c}{2\log 3}\frac {\log n}{\sqrt n}\sim 0$$..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $n$ is a perfect square, and identify its vertex set with $\{1,\ldots,\sqrt{n}\}^2$. Connect $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ if $a \neq c$ and $b \neq d$. You can identify a vertex from the set of its neighbors, so the open neighborhoods are all distinct. The number of maximal cliques is $\sqrt{n}!$, which isn't polynomial.

Comment: So for example if $n$ is $9$, would its vertex set be the cartesian product between $\{1, 2, 3\}$ with itself right?

Comment: Right, $\sqrt{9} = 3$ and $[3] = \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Amazing graphs. Assuming $n$ is a perfect square, are these graphs the ones having the maximum number of cliques while satisfying my conditions? They seem like Moon-Moser graphs with just the minimal modifications to satisfy my criteria, although the number of groups, instead of being $n/3$ of size $3$, are $\sqrt n$ of size $\sqrt n$.

Comment: They’re just the first thing that came to mind. No reason to believe that this construction is optimal, though who knows...